# Passing a value through a Route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a **app.tsx** component which has this following code:

```
<Route path="/situations/update/:id" element=<update />} />
```

I have a component called `styledMenu` which gets the `Id` as props from a different component.

In the styled menu there is a menu option called update which will take me to the **UPDATE PAGE ** where I need the ID

How do I set the navigation to that page and pass the `Id` along with that.

I had tried to use `useLocation` but it refreshed the value of `Id` every time I pressed the save button in update page. So that rendered the usage of `useLocation` useless.